# How can I implement a dialogue where the words appear as if they were being typed?

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm planning on putting a dialogue system into my game, I don't really work with surface so my way of implementing SDL_Ttf is by turning it into a texture, in other words, every paragraph would be shown within the rect, is there a way to make the words appear as if they were being typed?

Comment: you could use a for loop and modify a string so it shows more of it on each iteration of the loop

Comment: This is broad. Depending on how your game operates, works and looks like will depend on how dialogue is handled.

Answer (score 8):

What you may wish to do in this case is check the timer when you `started` printing the text on the screen and decide on an `amount` of time that it will take to print each letter in the paragraph.

Then each frame check the `time` and print this portion of the text:

```
int charsToPrint = (time - started) / amount;
if (amount < originalText.length()){
    printedPortion = originalText.substr(0, charsToPrint);
else
    //DONE: you may wish to do something else here?
    printedPortion = originalText;
```

You will probably want to play a sound when each when each letter is added. You could also accomplish this with a timer or check `if (amount > lastAmount) playSomeSound()...`

Comment: To make it more realistic, you can also vary the pauses between "typing" letters and insert longer pauses between words.